# Entity framework 6, ToListAsync is returned randomized data

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, repository-pattern

I'm working with EF6 (using MySQL provider)  and I've found the strange behavior. 
I use TakeWhereAsync method from my generic repository.

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<T>> TakeWhereAsync(Expression<Func<T, string>> sortExpression,
                                                       Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpression,
                                                       bool desc, int pageSize, int pageIndex)
    {
        var skipRows = (pageIndex - 1) * pageSize;

        var query = GetAllQuery().Where(whereExpression);
        query = desc
            ? query.OrderByDescending(sortExpression)
            : query.OrderBy(sortExpression);

        return await query.Skip(skipRows).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
    }
```

It returns absolutely unordered data.

[image: result after TakeWhereAsync]

I've tried to get SQL-request from IQueryable

[image: generated SQL-query]

and it's returned ordered data.

[image: result after query]

Can you please provide options to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure the `sortExpression` you are passing is correct? From the generated SQL looks like you are ordering by *constant* parameter value, in which case the order of the returned record is undefined.

Comment: Can you please show the code that calls `TakeWhereAsync` ? I agree with @Ivan that it looks like you've simply passed an incorrect sort expression; specifically, you're sorting by a parameter value (`@p__linq__0`). Are you perhaps passing `x => "Id"` as the sort expression? that doesn't sort by the `Id` column - it sorts by the string literal `"Id"`, which doesn't change per row: so doesn't apply a sort

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks, It's right remark. Can you post it as answer? Also, Can you provide realization for this method signature?

Comment: @MarcGravell https://www.screencast.com/t/JYfuY9rtwJ

Comment: @Imixal can I presume that `sortField` is a string there?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, sorry. full screen is https://www.screencast.com/t/mIFiRY4Y4u

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "realization". The implementation of the method is ok, the calling code is not ok. If you meant to use property name, there are several posts (I think the most popular being by @Marc :) showing how you can build expression from property/field name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion in comments, we have:

```
var testData = await _repository.TakeWhereAsync(_ => sortField, ...)
```

I'm presuming that `sortField` is a `string` here - perhaps `"Id"` - which means that you're sorting all the rows based on a constant: the string literal `"Id"`, which doesn't change per row. What you *actually* wanted was to sort on the column found by resolving that field. You can do this either by hard-coding a number of expected scenarios, or by building an expression tree based on reflection. A full example of how to do that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/233505/23354). Using the code in this answer, you would have:

```
string orderByField = "Id";
IQueryable<T> query = ... // from somewhere, your db context etc
query = query.OrderBy(orderByField); // using the code from the linked question
```